# how to pass data from datagridview to sql table in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with WPF with c# and I want to save the whole datagridview data into the sql table. I tried hard but its not working. Message box giving me error.

```
DataTable myview =new DataTable();
myview = (DataTable)my.DataContext;
string b="";
b = myview.Rows[0]["code"].ToString();
MessageBox mymessage1 = new MessageBox(b);
mymessage1.Show();
```

Comment: are we supposed to know what the message box error is..? you need to provide more valid information.. also what is it you are trying to do.. the code posted doesn't make sense to say the least.. do you know how to use the debugger..?

Comment: Also, your message box is not related to the saving, so just remove it and everything is fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF GridView has the property ItemsSource. The data context of the GridView is not the data contained within the view. I think you want something like `datatable = ((DataView)dg.ItemsSource).ToTable();` assuming there is already some data in the GridView

I guess (because you didn't tell us what the error was > In the future **always** tell **what** error) that because the `DataTable` was `null`, the `ToString()` method gave an `ArgumentNullException`

Comment: that not working ,it giving me error  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.